# Returning a general enum value with specific associated data

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to achieve returning a general enum value and determining one of it's parameters.

Something like this, given this enum:

```
enum {
state1(apple: Apple, color: Color)
state2(pear: Pear, color: Color)
...
}
```

I'd like to be able to return a state, and determining one of its' values.

```
...
switch state {
case .state1(_, _), .state2(_, _):
return state(...blue color...)
}
```

Is that possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you'll be able to get is to have a switch `case` for each `case` of your `enum`.  Then use pattern matching to get the values you want to keep and reconstruct the value you want.

Something like this:

```
enum Fruit {
    case state1(apple: Int, color: String)
    case state2(pear: Int, color: String)
}

var state = Fruit.state2(pear: 5, color: "green")

var newState: Fruit

switch state {
    case .state1(let x, _):
        newState = .state1(apple: x, color: "blue")
    case .state2(let x, _):
        newState = .state2(pear: x, color: "blue")
}

print(newState)
```

> ```
> state2(pear: 5, color: "blue")
> ```

Comment: Right. Trying to avoid that code duplication.. maybe something with a Template could help.